# Two different sites, two installations, no database or core sharing

Tags: installation, multi-sites

I've finished configuring a Drupal site using localhost (Mamp) but I have to wait some weeks until it gets uploaded to external host.

Now in the meantime I'd like to start developing another site that has nothing to do with the first one (different database, users, modules, etc). That is: I'd like to 'park' the old site and start creating the new one (new Drupal 7 installation) without affecting the first one.

I'm using Mamp 3.0.7.2 and the server route is default (Mamp--- htdocs)

Any hint on what to begin with?

Thank you

Comment: Strikes me this is more of a MAMP question than a Drupal question? In any event surely you can just create a tarball of your site's root directory ready for uploading and move it somewhere suitable. Then start your new site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. put your drupal sites in separate subdirectories of htdocs, e.g .../htdocs/site1, ...htdocs/site2
2. access your sites using the mamp localhost url, e.g. `http://localhost/site1`

If you know how, you can also create virtualhosts in /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf and edit /etc/hosts on your mac, so that you can access the sites with whichever url you choose, such as:

```
http://site1.local
```

Databases: just upload your databases using MAMP's phpmyadmin, and edit your sites' settings.php to use the respective databases.

Comment: Thank you, that worked out perfectly fine! Only I can´t access the Admin menu, but that seems to be a Chrome issue: Firefox runs it OK. Thanks again